# 5.25" RAM-Disk which takes old DDR RAM

Tags: hard-disk, sata

I have about 8 or 10 DDR-2 and 6 DDR-3 modules which I don't really need any more. I wonder whether there's a 5.25" SATA hard disk drive that takes DDR RAM (you can recommend for DDR-2 or DDR-3).

From the size of a 5.25" drive I'd estimate that it could have ~10 slots but 8 would also be ok, so it would be able to be a 16 GB to 20 GB disk.

From the performance, it should be able to outperform an SSD when it comes to writing speed, i.e. it should be higher than 500 MB/s.

The price should not exceed 35 €.

Comment: You know that ram looses all its data the moment it gets no power, don't you?

Comment: @JulianKuchlbauer: yes, sure. It would take temporary data, e.g. as a cache for video editing or similar.

Comment: you can get 32gb ram in PC and create huge ram disk safely there. Why even bother with old ddrs? Just sold them on ebay..

Comment: @JIV: Buying 32 GB or RAM for a RAM disk is ~200 €, Next I how do I put additional 32 GB of RAM into my PC when all slots are already full? And don't forget that I need to upgrade from Windows Home edition to Windows Professional. This exceeds the total cost expectations.

Answer (score 1):

So technically, YES, [there is such a thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I-RAM#Second_Generation_i-RAM): The **Gigabyte i-RAM (second generation)**.

However, its performance is limited to the SATA I spec, so you're not really going to get a whole lot of good stuff out of it. It's also incredibly rare - but sometimes they do go for cheap.

It's probably a better bet to put those guys into a computer that can use them as a RAM disk and then make that network attached storage over a gigabit ethernet line.

Comment: I'd not like to waste that much power by putting them into a separate PC. Also: Gigabit Ethernet is limited to 125 MB/s.

Comment: Ah, but you can team it, and it's not limited to 4gb